# How to fill an entire div with one character

Tags: javascript, html

I need decorative sidebars full of * characters, I created two side-divs with many *, the problem is that their height is relative to the main content of the site so sometimes they're too much or they aren't enough. I'll like to know if there's something like a javascript function to write a certain character until the div "ends".

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you're looking for and what you've tried?

Answer (score 5):

non-JS solution:

Create a PNG with a single asterisk and use that as repeating background image via CSS.

That means:

- You don't need to know which size the rendered element has;
- you don't need to get a char-count calculated using the current font-size settings;
- the decoration is visible even without JS (e.g in a subway, where half of the page wasn't loaded)

Answer (score 2):

Put in as much content as you could possible need and then use `overflow: hidden` to clip it to the box:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #aff;
}
```

```html
<div>* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *</div>
```