# Fill DIV with asterisks & to be printed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if there is a way and, if so, how can I have a div filled with asterisks (*) without knowing its exact width, but I want to keep it on a single row (like a border).

I know one of the best ways would be to have an asterisk image and set my DIV's borders using this image but it's quite impossible in my case to use this, as I would like to only have a single HTML page and no linked images.

So, how can I have a complete DIV filled with "*" (Asterisks) and having this DIV width not fixed?

**Edit**

In addition, this must be printed. So, I have to forget the possibility of having an asterisk image set as background of my DIV because of userside option which allows or not to print background image.

Comment: Yes, CSS and javascript (if possible, no javascript but if nothing else possible, javascript can be an option)

Comment: I'm not clear on the filling a div and keep it on a single row part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fill an entire div with one character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714352/how-to-fill-an-entire-div-with-one-character)

Comment: @ctwheels His answer is in fact not working (with Chrome) I get multiple rows... But my question indeed is the same as mainly asked question I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only issue is to avoid an external file, then use a [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) for the image.

example

```css
div {
  height:14px;
  border-width:7px 0 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHBAMAAAA2fErgAAAAJFBMVEX///+KioowMDBAQEAMDAxiYmLm5ubMzMxQUFC2trYiIiIAAAA2IPbUAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACVJREFUCB1jYAADLiDJNaOKgYEtpIGBgcO4mYGBk4kTKMjIwAAAMvcC1AqHZy8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=') 7 0 0 repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="asterisk"></div>
```

---

Update with border image (*which gets printed*)

```css
div {
  height:14px;
  border-width:7px 0 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHBAMAAAA2fErgAAAAJFBMVEX///+KioowMDBAQEAMDAxiYmLm5ubMzMxQUFC2trYiIiIAAAA2IPbUAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACVJREFUCB1jYAADLiDJNaOKgYEtpIGBgcO4mYGBk4kTKMjIwAAAMvcC1AqHZy8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=') 7 0 0 repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="asterisk"></div>
```

Comment: Is there another way than image anyway? Because, I know it can split image in the middle in case page stop before the end of image...

Comment: Since I'm guessing this is purely ornamental, using an image would probably be better than filling a div with actual asterisks

Comment: @SimonDugré since it is not an external image, and since it is extremely small i cannot think of a way to stop its loading..

Comment: You guys are right. It is working perfectly. Thank to you.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli See my edit... this must be print. Is there a way to have this print? Because I know background printing is userside option.

Comment: @SimonDugré added a variant that uses the image as a border, so that it prints.

Answer (score 1):

You could try measuring the width of an asterisk (call it `w`) then divide the width of the `div` to fill by `w` to find the number of asterisks to use.

HTML:

```
<div id="calc-width" style="display: none">*</div>
<div id="fill" style="width: 150px; border: 1px solid black"></div>
```

JS:

```
var n = ~~($('#fill').width() / $('#calc-width').width());
var chars = Array(n + 1).join('*');
$('#fill').html(chars);
```

This is likely prone to a few errors, you'll want to give it a thorough check.  Used jQuery here for brevity but it can be easily translated into vanilla javascript.

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/dvfcm1ud/1/

Comment: This may be my only option so far as I my page must be print and doing it this way make them print contrary to @GabyakaG.Petrioli's answer.

Comment: Although measuring appears to give few errors, you could also adapt the code so that you fill the div in a loop and check for its size in the same loop. As soon as its height grows, it means that was the asterisk too much, you can exit the loop and remove the last asterisk. Not sure how elegant this would look though and I'm currently on an ipad so trying it in a fiddle is too complicated for me to try and show.